# Authorising the request with additional Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logic, owin

A portal which enables `Student`(`role`) to take an exam through their login.

There is another type of exam in the portal which is mandatory to taken from the exam centre only.
An exam centre is a place which has a `Supervisor`(`role`) assigned to it.

**My Question**

To take an exam student will need to be at centre, so whenever he wants to take exam an additional authorization for Supervisor will pop up in user's screen, which on successful authorization will then only render questions for exam.

How to achieve this?

My current auth is on `owin` based token generation in `WebApi`.

**Explaination**
any Supervisor at the centre will need to enter his creds in between student log in their creds and hit Start Exam. Basically that exam needs two authorization at the same time one for student taking the exam and supervisor taking the exam.. here supervisor don't need to login to his account separately, it is some what 2 step auth, where two creds need to be authenticated before performing the action

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're getting at there. Do you mean a `Student` can't take an exam until a `Supervisor` is also logged in?

Comment: @scgough any `Supervisor` at the centre will need to enter his creds in between  `student` log in there creds and hit Start Exam. Basically that exam two authorization at the same time one for student taking the exam and supervisor taking the exam..

here supervisor dont need to login to his account separaetly , it is some what 2 step auth, where two creds need to be authenticated before performing the action